# Sumproduct vba Macro how to stop the loop process

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sumproduct

I have a working code that will do a sumproduct calculation with 2 criteria and then feed the results by match to a dictionary and then paste them as 1 output.

the source data is formatted in a pivot table so it is already sorted by the sumproduct range criteria. sample below.

The issue i am trying to solve is, that the code will run through the entire pivot table trying to find the next match to the current one it found. Since the data is sorted in a pivot, there won't be a next match once the first mismatch has been found. How can I stop the code at that point to shorten the loop? It is at this point in the code: (If UCase(arrI(i, 1)) = UCase(arrI(j, 1)) And arrI(i, 2) = arrI(j, 2) Then when code goes to next J / next line in data)

```
Sub weighted_averagek()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arrI As Variant, arrF As Variant, lastR As Long
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, pCount As Double, d As Object, pcount2 As Double, pcount3 As Double


  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  arrI = sh.Range("A2:F" & lastR).Value
  ReDim arrF(1 To UBound(arrI, 1), 1 To 1)
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  For i = 1 To lastR - 1
    If Not d.Exists(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2))) Then
        For j = 1 To lastR - 1
            If UCase(arrI(i, 1)) = UCase(arrI(j, 1)) And arrI(i, 2) = arrI(j, 2) Then
                On Error GoTo missingrate
                pCount = pCount + (arrI(j, 6) * arrI(j, 5))
                pcount2 = pcount2 + arrI(j, 6)
                pcount3 = pCount / pcount2
missingrate:
            End If
        Next j
        d(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2))) = pcount3
        arrF(i, 1) = pcount3: pcount3 = 0: pCount = 0: pcount2 = 0
    Else
        arrF(i, 1) = d(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2)))
    End If
  Next
  sh.Range("G2").Resize(UBound(arrF, 1), 1).Value = arrF

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please, try inserting `Exit For` after `missingrate:` label, if you rally want doing what you say. But, if you need your code to also run the lines `d(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2))) = pcount3` `arrF(i, 1) = pcount3: pcount3 = 0: pCount = 0: pcount2 = 0` you should create a Boolean variable `Dim boolStop As Boolean` and place `boolStop = True` instead of the above recommended `Exit For`. Then, after the two above code lines place: `If boolStop then boolStop = False: Exit For`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found a workaround to shorten the loop as well by setting i and j value to the row value when the first mismatch occurs. That way the code will write the match to the dictionary and continue at the next row instead of the very first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  xi = 1
  yj = 1
  
  For i = xi To lastR - 1
    If Not d.Exists(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2))) Then
        For j = yj To lastR - 1
            If UCase(arrI(i, 1)) = UCase(arrI(j, 1)) And arrI(i, 2) = arrI(j, 2) Then
                             
                On Error GoTo missingrate
                pCount = pCount + (arrI(j, 6) * arrI(j, 5))
                pcount2 = pcount2 + arrI(j, 6)
                pcount3 = pCount / pcount2
missingrate:
                Else: If UCase(arrI(i, 1)) <> UCase(arrI(j, 1)) Or arrI(i, 2) <> arrI(j, 2) Then GoTo newmatchID

            End If
        Next j

newmatchID:
        
        d(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2))) = pcount3
        arrF(i, 1) = pcount3: pcount3 = 0: pCount = 0: pcount2 = 0
    Else
        arrF(i, 1) = d(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2)))
    End If
  yj = j
  xi = j
```